# Where do I find the file uploaded to Google drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Based on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462870/how-do-i-convert-google-docs-file-template-for-document-stored-on-google-drive), we are creating a pdf from a Google Document. The pdf is uploaded to Google Drive.

```
    self.GOOGLEDOCUMENTS_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata']
    
    # Set the permission for the google sheet
    self.documents_permission = {
        'role' : 'reader',            
        'type' : 'anyone',
        'value' : 'anyone'
    }


    document_credentials, document_project_id     = 
        auth.default(scopes=self.GOOGLEDOCUMENTS_SCOPES)  # Returns a tuple.                
        self.document_credentials    = document_credentials
        self.document_project_id     = document_project_id
```

1. We create the google document using the Google Doc API

   ```
            title = "file name for doc"
            body    = {                         
                'title': title,                        
            }
            document_service                = build('docs',     'v1', credentials=self.document_credentials)
            create_document_response        = document_service.documents().create(body=body).execute()
            document_Id                     = create_document_response.get("documentId")
   ```
2. We then use export_media to create a pdf of the google doc

   ```
                    media_pdf_request   = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=document_Id, mimeType="application/pdf")                                                
                    file                = io.BytesIO()                                                
                    downloader          = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, media_pdf_request)
                    done                = False
                    while done is False:
                        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()                        

                    file_content        = file.getvalue()                        
                    file_metadata       =  {'name' : filename_statement,'mimeType': 'application/pdf'}                            

                    media                   = MediaIoBaseUpload(io.BytesIO(file_content),mimetype='application/pdf', resumable=True)
                    pdf_file = (
                        drive_service.files()
                        .create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id")
                        .execute()
                    )
                pdf_file_name       = pdf_file.get("id")

                doc_res = drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=pdf_file_name,                    
                    body=self.documents_permission,                           
                    fields='id').execute()

                pdf_file_id     = doc_res.get('id')

                statement_link              = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + document_Id                            
                drive_link                  = "https://drive.google.com/drive/" + pdf_file_name
   ```

We expect the file to be accessible at

```
drive_link                  = "https://drive.google.com/drive/" + pdf_file_name
```

Unfortunately we get a 404 error. Please help.

UPDATE -

We changed the drive link to the following -

```
drive_link = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + pdf_file_name
```

But we get at 403 error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: File ID is not file name. The file should be accessible (if it is accessible) at `pdf_file.get("webContentLink")`.

Comment: Hi Amandan webContentLink returns Null , but get('id') return a valid file-id

Comment: Show us exactly how you are trying to download the file.

Comment: @JohnGordon - As listed in the above code 1) We use export_media to convert Google doc to pdf. 2) Use MediaIoBaseDownload to Download the pdf file as bytes. 3) We upload the bytes to a file in Google drive using MediaIoBaseUpload.

Comment: Using the same permissions we are able to access the Google doc (which was also created using Google API) at https://docs.google.com/document/d/document_id

Comment: From a comment of `I think we got past this error. But we have another question related to this here - stackoverflow.com/questions/77917382/… . Can you please help?` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66467631), I saw this question. Can you provide your whole script without removing your personal information? And, how is the Google Document of `document_Id` created?

Comment: I have updated my question with details on how we create the Google Document and how we get the document_id

Comment: @Jack tileman Thank you for replying. About `I have updated how we create the Google Document and how we get the document_id`, in your updated question, your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue of `The request is missing a valid API key.` is shown without your personal information. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: My issues is I am not able to get a URI link to access to the pdf file that I created in Google Drive

Comment: Should I be using - drive_link = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + pdf_file_name ?

Comment: When I use the above I get "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",

Comment: We are able to successfully access the Google doc using - "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + document_Id

Comment: @tanaike - correct. The whole script is there without any personal information.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `@tanaike - correct. The whole script is there without any personal information.`, I understood it. When I could correctly replicate your issue and find a solution, I would like to tell you here.

Comment: I have added details on how we create the credentials using auth.default

Comment: @Tanaike - Just wanted to check if you were able to reproduce the issue? Any pointers towards a solution?